# Python requests return 403 error code even after setting required headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to parse a page using Python Request module.  However, the problem is that it returns the 403 code.

This is the page I am trying to parse.  I used google chrome to debug and check what request headers are being sent and have set those as part of request. however I am still getting 403 error.

https://www.autotrader.ca/a/Honda/Accord+Sedan/Burlington/Ontario/5_42423732_ON20081215113610906/

And this is my code.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br'
    }

resp = requests.get("https://www.autotrader.ca/a/Honda/Accord+Sedan/Burlington/Ontario/5_42423732_ON20081215113610906/",
                    headers=headers)

print(resp.status_code)
```

**update:**
if copy the exact cookie from chrome inspector and set in header then it's working as expected. so I assume I need to generate a cookie somehow, not sure though.

Comment: Just tested your code and i am getting resp code 200.

Comment: @Paandittya that's weird, I am getting 403 error code.

Comment: @Paandittya, could be as you are able to execute it successfully, however if i set cookie I get `200`